# How to get all the index patterns which never had any documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

For Kibana server decommissioning purposes, I want to get a list of index patterns which never had any single document and had documents.

How to achieve this using Kibana only?
I tried this but it doesn't give the list based on the document count.

```
GET /_cat/indices
```

Also in individual level getting the count to check the documents are there  is time consuming .

```
GET index-pattern*/_count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. V is for verbose and s stands for sort.

```
GET /_cat/indices?v&s=store.size:desc
```

From the docs :

These metrics are retrieved directly from Lucene, which {es} uses internally to power indexing and search. As a result, all document counts include hidden nested documents.

Comment: Thank you but it gives an output like this. 1622631321 10:55:21 643642666

Comment: How about this _cat/indices?v ? v is for verbose.

Comment: It's helpful can we sort using document count ?

Comment: GET /_cat/indices?v&s=store.size:desc, does this work?

Comment: `GET /_cat/indices?v&s=store.size:desc` fetches a list of indices, not index patterns.